# Обобщенные массивы Java

Tags: java, массивы

Необходимо создать обобщенный класс, порождающий динамические одномерные массивы с элементами различных типов. 
Собственно вопрос: есть ли какие-нибудь костыли для того, чтобы всё-таки можно было создавать обобщенные массивы?

Comment: что мешает погуглить самому? http://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/2604639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Юзать дженерики?

Например

```
class Container<T> {
    T[] = new T[10];
}
```

И собственно зачем? Можно создать массив `Object[]`. Но не проще ли использовать `ArrayList` и не париться?

Comment: Не, не откомпилируется. Это ж вам не C# с реифицированными дженериками.